# Hangman Program so far

Tags: python, python-2.7

So my program is this so far:

```
def update():

    print word
    counter = 0
    blanks = len(word)*'-'
    blank_list = list(blanks)
    letter = raw_input('Please enter a single letter: ')

    for index in range(len(word)):
        if letter in word[index]:
            blank_list[index] = letter
            print ''.join(blank_list)
            letter = raw_input('Please enter a single letter: ')
```

but when I enter a correct letter in the wrong order it displays it as an incorrect guess, ie, one of my words is horse, if i entered an o it would display -o---, but if I entered an h, it would come up as None, because  haven't set parameters of what to do when it is incorrect guess. This goes for when it is if letter in word[index] or if letter == word[index].
any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

Comment: Most of that code isn't relevant, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I think just _fixing your code_ won't help you much. Please try and focus on what you want to do. All that drawing of the actual hangman doesn't matter. You have three things in a game of hangman: the word you need to guess, a list of correctly guessed letters, and the number of wrong guesses. The game is won if the list of correct guesses has all the letters needed to build the word (i.e. `set(word) == set(correct_letters)`).

Comment: @Carsten I am more looking for help on a way that will allow it to let the letters be guessed in a different order then in the word, for example, one of my words is horse, if I entered an o for my first guess it will mark it down as a correct guess, it if for the second guess I guess an h on the next guess it will mark it as a wrong guess

Answer (score 1):

Here, you enforce order by looking at the exact index:

```
if letter == word[index]
```

You want to ask `if letter in word`. You can also find the exact index of the letter with `word.index(letter)` (careful with repeated letters).

Comment: still comes up with the same problem where it will accept the first one, but if a letter is entered that comes before the first correct guess it will count as incorrect

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you have a for loop based on index so when you enter a correct answer the next correct letter has to be in a later index because you already passed the previous indexes. For a hangman program I might do something with a while loop and use a count like you have and if the count exceeds your limit then break the while loop and make you word a list of letters. Then check to see if your guessed letter is within your list of letters of the word.

so if your guess limit is 5 then do something like

break word into list
set guess count to 0

while guess_count < 5:
    if letter in word_list:
        #update
    else:
        guess_count += 1

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your guesses are based on indexing. Once you guess a letter, you cannot guess one before that.

**Running your code:**

```
>>> update('mouse')
mouse
Please enter a single letter: m
m----
Please enter a single letter: u
m-u--
Please enter a single letter: o
>>>
```

It exits because the placing of `'u'` is after that of `'o'`. Instead change your code to this:

```
def update(word):
        found = False
        guesses_left = 3
        blank_list = list(len(word)*'_')
        while guesses_left > 0:
                letter = raw_input('Enter your letter: ')
                for k in range(len(word)):
                        if word[k] == letter and letter not in blank_list:
                                blank_list[k] = letter
                                found = True
                if found == False:
                        guesses_left-=1
                else:
                        found = False
                print ''.join(blank_list)
                if '_' not in blank_list:
                    break
        if guesses_left < 1:
            print 'You lost!'
        else:
            print 'You won!'
```

**Running my code:**

```
>>> update('mouse')
Enter your letter: m
m____
Enter your letter: s
m__s_
Enter your letter: u
m_us_
Enter your letter: o
mous_
Enter your letter: e
mouse
You won!
>>>
```